# Copying files from one directory to another directory in jenkins master machine

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am trying to copying files from one directory to another directory in Jenkins master machine facing access denied issue while executing in the shell script

> cp -a /usr/lib/hook/pm2-logs/. /usr/lib/hook/Hook_Log_Backup/

**Issue:**

> cp: cannot create regular file
>   '/usr/lib/hook/Hook_Log_Backup/./pr_hook_out-0.log': Permission
>   denied cp: cannot create regular file
>   '/usr/lib/hook/Hook_Log_Backup/./pr_hook_err-0.log': Permission
>   denied cp: cannot create regular file
>   '/usr/lib/hook/Hook_Log_Backup/./system_hook_out-1.log':
>   Permission denied cp: cannot create regular file
>   '/usr/lib/hook/Hook_Log_Backup/./system_hook_err-1.log':
>   Permission denied cp: cannot create regular file
>   '/usr/lib/hook/Hook_Log_Backup/./common_hook_out-2.log':
>   Permission denied

Comment: did you try -rf option or check if permissions for the directory are set to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write to your machine path (/usr/lib/); It means your user running Jenkins does not have write access to that directory (or it's parent directory). If the user running Jenkins has access to do sudo on the machine; you can try it with 'sudo cp'